# g++ errors when trying to compile c++11 with Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, gcc, c++11, rcpp

**SYSTEM SPEC:**

- **OS**   - Mac OS X 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard)
- **g++**  - Macports gcc 4.8.1_2+universal
- **R**    - 2.15.3
- **Rcpp** - 0.10.3

I keep on receiving an error when I am trying to compile functions that use C++11 in R (through Rcpp) - for some reason, g++ does not recognise `-std=c++11` option.

This example is taken from Rcpp help files (it does not contain anything specific to C++11, but can show what my problem is). If I try running:

```
require( Rcpp )
Sys.setenv( "PKG_CXXFLAGS"="-std=c++11" )
cppFunction(plugins=c("cpp11"), '
int useCpp11() {
    int x = 10;
    return x;
}')
```

I get:

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
make: *** [file61239328ae6.o] Error 1
g++ -arch x86_64 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/x86_64 -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include  -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/Rcpp/include"   -std=c++11  -fPIC  -g -O2  -c file61239328ae6.cpp -o file61239328ae6.o 
Error in sourceCpp(code = code, env = env, rebuild = rebuild, showOutput = showOutput,  : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.
```

At the same time, I can compile this function directly from bash - if this code is in `useCpp11.cpp` file, then this runs without any complaints:

```
g++ useCpp11.cpp -std=c++11
```

Certainly, I am doing something wrong, but I cannot work out what it is. gcc 4.8 is set as a default compiler in bash, Rcpp has been working without fault in the past. I suspect that I am not telling R which version of g++ to use - could that be the case?

Comment: If your on a mac just use clang

Comment: I also need my code to work on Windows and Linux...

Comment: Try passing "-v" instead of "-std=c++11" to confirm your suspicion that the wrong gcc version is being selected.

Comment: What is the output of running `Sys.getenv()["PATH"]` in an R session? Is there an older `g++` being accessed first from one of those directories? Try forcing use of that particular `g++` with `Sys.setenv(CXX=<full_path_to_g++>)`.

Comment: @user1131467 - you are absolutely right, the darn thing still uses 4.2.1. What's the best way of handling it - shall I follow Kevin's advice?

Comment: @KevinUshey, would adding CXX env be sufficient?

Comment: I think the best solution is to create a file `~/.R/Makevars`, and have your make flags and such in there. So you can set `CXX=<path_to_g++>` and not have to worry about it from then on.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Kevin Ushley is absolutely right - the easiest way to make sure that the right compiler is being used is through `Makevars` file. In my case, I added:

```
CXX = g++-4.8.1
PKG_CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11
```

This is what I have been missing - and it all worked afterwards. This works if you are compiling your package.

Comment: I use the exact same mechanism -- but using it the way you describe it here prevents you from creating CRAN-compatible package as the C++11 option is now global (and we are not allowed to upload C++11 code).

Comment: I don't mind that it is not CRAN-compatible - it's all written for internal use. It is a good job that we've managed to solve this one - details like these matter and often stand between users and good code :-)

Comment: Just noting that for some reason it was ignored when I put it in the `src/Makevars` inside the package, but as soon as I put it in `~/.R/Makevars` it worked.

Answer (score 7):

Quick ones:

- you **are behind** on Rcpp which is at a released version 0.10.4
- the version you are using (0.10.3) *does have have a plugin for C++11*
- there is [an entire article at the Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/first-steps-with-C++11/) which details this.

So allow me to quote from that [C++11 piece on the Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/first-steps-with-C++11/):

```
R> library(Rcpp)
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/cpp11.cpp")
R> useAuto()
[1] 42
R>
```

where the code in `/tmp/cpp11.cpp` is as follows:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// Enable C++11 via this plugin (Rcpp 0.10.3 or later)
// [[Rcpp::plugins("cpp11")]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int useAuto() {
    auto val = 42;      // val will be of type int
    return val;
}
```

If that does not work for you, then your system is not set up right. In other words, this is not a question for the `Rcpp` tag -- but rather for 'how do I set up my path to invoke the version of g++ I think I should be invoking'.

Comment: Dirk, got it - I am out of date on R which is why I did not see 0.10.4. I have read your articles prior to posting and found them very informative - however, my problem was with my system set-up, you were exactly right.

I did not know how to enforce R to use the compiler of my choice rather than the default one (which, in my case, does not support C++11).

Comment: Good to know. You need to sort out your `$PATH` and installation. Also, please feel free to 'accept' the answer (click on the tick-mark) and/or upvote it (click on on the 'up' triangle).

Comment: On my setup (R 3.4.2, Rcpp 0.12.12, clang LLVM 9.0.0 on x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0), adding `[[Rcpp::plugins("cpp11")]]` doesn't seem to be enough.  I also have to add `PKG_CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11` to my `Makevars` or else the flag doesn't get added to the commands, and I get warnings like `warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension`.

Comment: You confused what command-line usage does ("plugins" for `cxxFunction()` or `sourceCpp()`) and what packages do ("src/Makevars").  There is no intersection here.  Two different uses.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to fix up your path you can set the `PKG_CXXFLAGS` environment variable just prior to compiling.

```
     export PKG_CXXFLAGS='`Rscript -e "Rcpp:::CxxFlags()"` -std=c++11'
```

For example:

In **R**

```
#generate the bare Rcpp package as usual
library(Rcpp)
Rcpp.package.skeleton("Foo",
                      example_code=FALSE,
                      attributes=TRUE,
                      cpp_files=c("./Foo_R_wrapper.cpp", "./Foo.h", "/Foo.cpp")
                     )
```

and in **Bash**

```
#tell the compiler to use C++11
export PKG_CXXFLAGS='`Rscript -e "Rcpp:::CxxFlags()"` -std=c++11'

#compile as usual
cd ./Foo/;
R -e 'Rcpp::compileAttributes(".",verbose=TRUE)';
cd ..;

R CMD build Foo;
#ensure that there are no bugs
R CMD check Foo;
```

where **Foo_R_wrapper.cpp** wraps a C++ function FooBar defined and implemented in **Foo.h** and **Foo.cpp** respectively.

**Foo_R_wrapper.cpp** could contain the following:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>                                   

#include "Foo.h"                                    

// [[Rcpp::export]]                                 
SEXP FooBar(SEXP baa)
{                                                   
    Rcpp::NumericVector baa_vec(baa)
    //Do something from Foo.h (to baa_vec?)
    ...
    //etc
    return baa_vec;
}
```