# The tools required to build C++ code for R were not found

Tags: c++, r, ubuntu-14.04

```
OS: Ubuntu 14.04
g++: g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4
R version: 3.2.0 (2015-04-16) -- "Full of Ingredients"
Rcpp: 0.11.6
```

Today I `apt-get dist-upgrade` my system, and the g++ was also been upgraded.
Then when I am trying to use "Rcpp" package in R, the code is the simplest test code `>>evalCpp("1+1")` . An error as follows occurred:

```
Error in frameTypes(env) : not a proper evaluation environment
Calls: ::: ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted

Error in sourceCpp(code = code, env = env, rebuild = rebuild,showOutput = showOutput,  : 
Error 1 occurred building shared library.

WARNING: The tools required to build C++ code for R were not found.

Please install GNU development tools including a C++ compiler.
```

I have did google for it. The following links are all about Mac OSX:

[Error when with Xcode 5.0 and Rcpp (Command Line Tools ARE installed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503995/error-when-with-xcode-5-0-and-rcpp-command-line-tools-are-installed)

[g++ errors when trying to compile c++11 with Rcpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453182/g-errors-when-trying-to-compile-c11-with-rcpp)

From the answers and comments, I can not tell what is the real problem.
Appreciate your help!

UPDATE: I finally solved this problem by reinstalling all the `R` related deb packages. And one thing we should keep in mind is that I also did what @Dirk suggested first `apt-get build-dep r-base-dev`. I can not confirm which one is the key step.

Comment: Assuming this isn't solved yet, give me a hint: what command triggers the error message that you report?  Also, the versions that you report don't agree with what I see.  Can you run `cat /etc/issue.net` and report the results?

Comment: @nobar It is just the simplest Rcpp test code ：evalCpp("1+1")

Comment: `evalCpp("1+1")` works fine for me on Ubuntu 14.04.1.  But like I said, your various package versions don't seem to make sense.  I think there is a bit of ambiguity about what you are running after doing the dist-upgrade.  Maybe you should do a [full-upgrade](http://askubuntu.com/a/81594/11522) to get your package versions straightened out.

Comment: @nobar I have seen your comment under http://askubuntu.com/a/81594/11522 . I don't see `full-upgrade` option either. Have you figure out the reason?

Comment: Nope.  It isn't in my man-pages and the command doesn't support it.  I recommended it to you based only on that post -- which turned out to be incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```
 sudo apt-get build-dep r-base
```

to install the all the build dependencies for R itself.

But we even built an explicitly helper package `r-base-dev` so *in most cases* (and in your use case of [Rcpp](http://www.rcpp.org)) you just need

```
 sudo apt-get install r-base-dev
```

Comment: Really thank you for your help, I shall test your solution later and post the result. Since I am not accessible to my computer. But what I am curious is why this problem happen? Is there any permanent solution? If next time I upgrade g++ , will this problem happen again?

Comment: Yes, it is permanent. No, you do not need to do it again.  Also look at the [Rcpp FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-FAQ.pdf) and other documentation.

Comment: I have followed your solution and still got the same error. And the final solution is that I reinstalled all the `r-base-core` related packages. And off course the `sudo apt-get build-dep r-base` does pull some extra packages first before reinstallation. I am not sure which procedure is the key ingredient, or both. Anyway I thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong/missing in your system configuration.  First of all, I doubt that you are really running Ubuntu 14.04 (after the dist-upgrade) because the the other versions that you listed wouldn't be available (unless you have pulled them in from a non-default repository).  You might also consider running a  [full-upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/a/81594/11522) to try to straighten out your configuration.

You *might* gain some insights by running with `showOutput=1`...

```
library(Rcpp)
evalCpp("1+1",showOutput=1,rebuild=1)
```

...but actually, it looks like the problem is related specifically to a parameter called `env` (`Error in frameTypes(env) : not a proper evaluation environment`) which is likely evaluated prior-to attempting to compile.

For what it is worth, I was able to run this without `r-base-dev` installed, but maybe installing `r-base-dev` will pull in the correct, and updated, versions of what you need.  I would be inclined to just reinstall all R-related packages.

Comment: I always use `apt-get dist-upgrade` to update my system. And I have used an non-default repository for `CRAN`: http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu/trusty/

Comment: @lovelyzlf: I actually don't know too much about `apt-get` upgrade options because I never do it that way.  What I see, though, is that *none* of the versions that you indicated are available from the 14.04.1 default repositories ([including g++](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/g++-4.8)) -- and that was a red flag.  Not that it matters -- I suspect you just need a clean install of R and its packages (but preferably not so bleeding edge).

Comment: The final solution is reinstallation! See the comments I give for @Dirk's answer. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @lovelyzlf: Great!  Then my suggestion worked: "I would be inclined to just reinstall all R-related packages".

Comment: Yes, you got the up vote! And I got the g++ info from `g++ --version` and it is a little bit different from what you see form the `Synaptic Package Manager`.